# How to find the largest rectangle in a 2D array formed by four identical corners?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, multidimensional-array

Consider this array:

```
[
  ["B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A"],
  ["B", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"],
  ["B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B"],
  ["B", "B", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A"],
  ["A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "C", "C", "B", "A", "C"],
  ["A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "C"],
  ["C", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A"]
]
```

I’m trying to get the width and height of the rectangle with the largest area in this 2D array. The answer should be 8 * 4 = 32 (coordinates (1, 1), (1, 8), (4, 1) and (4, 8)), since it has the largest area with the same corners `"A"`.

[image: Visual representation of the 2D array: here, the letters are color coded. The A’s are blue, and this largest rectangle, where all four corners are blue, is highlighted.]

Comment: I can't see the rectangle of your solution

Comment: What do you mean by a rectangle?

Comment: The edges are should same value (ex ([1,1]="A", [1,8]="A", [4,1]="A"[4,8]="A")

Comment: You should explain that A, B, C are *colors* and you want to find 4 *corners of same color*.

Comment: Define also what is a *large* rectange: greatest *area* or *perimeter*?

Comment: Sorry, i want a greatest area !

Comment: I guess this answer is not unclear. I understood it just reading first time. Not fear to close it for this reason.

Comment: I’ve edited the question myself now, and voted to reopen. It’s too interesting to remain on hold. This would probably also be a great question on [codegolf.se].

Comment: @Xufox, LOL! Just posted! https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161538/largest-rectangle-in-2d-array-in-javascript  ( before read your comment )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because was funny:

```
var l = [ 
["B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A"],
["B", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"],
["B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B"],
["B", "B", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A"],
["A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "C", "C", "B", "A", "C"],
["A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "C"],
["C", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A"]];

var squares = [];
//for each position
for (var column=0; column< l[0].length; column++) 
   for (var row=0; row< l.length ; row++ ) 
    //look for all scuares from this position:
    for (var next_column = column+1; next_column < l[0].length; next_column++ )
        if ( l[row][next_column] == l[row][column] )
            for (var next_row = row+1; next_row < l.length; next_row++)
               //if it is a square
               if (l[next_row][column] == l[row][column] && 
                   l[next_row][next_column] == l[row][column]) 
                    //annotate square
                    squares.push( [ column, row, next_column, next_row  ] );

//get areas from squares
var area_l = squares.map(function(an_square) { 
    return (an_square[2]-an_square[0]+1)*(an_square[3]-an_square[1]+1);
  });

//search for big area
var max_area_index = area_l.indexOf(Math.max(  ...area_l  ));

//here it is
console.log( squares[max_area_index] );
```

> **Result:** Array(4) [1, 1, 8, 4]

Comment: Just thinking about the time complexity, this is O(m²n²), right? I think, an approach where you would test every possible rectangle, starting with the largest, then decreasing in size, could yield an O(n³) solution.

Comment: hi @Xufox, thanks about comments :) I didn't optimize it, just wrote in one shot. I like your question. May be someone can answer it also someone else can come through with a nice optimization or more elegant approach. I'm not JS developer, is evident.

Comment: Actually, never mind… I was thinking about every possible square. Every possible rectangle could have worse time complexity, though the part about starting with the largest, then decreasing in size could be worth thinking about.

Comment: @Xufox, an heuristic rule may be "don't search for rectangles smaller than the biggest found".

Comment: @Xufox: I have a solution like this, waiting to get the OP unlocked

Answer (score 1):

If we consider that:

1. Small rectangles have **same probability** of having 4 identical corners as big rectangles
2. A point can be a corner of as many rectangles **as any other point** whatever its position (`N = (width-1)*(height-1)`)

So we confirm the intuitive algorithm: **we want to look for the bigger rectangles first**, which are more likely to have corners on the sides rather than in the center, and stop quickly when we find them.

### Approach 1: strict ordering of rectangles by area

This solution computes the shape of big rectangles so as to look for them.

The hard part is that ordering rectangles by area is not as easy as narrowing squares or circles. Rectangles of area 12 can have shape of [1,12], [2,6], [3,4], [4,3], [6,2] or [12,1] while rectangles of area 11 can only have shape of [1,11] or [11,1].

```
function getGreatestRectangleStrict () {
    let hMax = tab.length - 1,
        wMax = tab[0].length - 1;
    // Search valid rectangle by decreasing area
    for (let area = (hMax+1)*(wMax+1); area >= 0; --area) {
        // Compute rectangle shapes that fit in tab with given area
        let kMax = Math.min(area, hMax + 1);
        for (let k = 1; k <= kMax ; ++k)
            if (area % k === 0) {
                let height = k - 1,
                    width = area / k - 1;
                if ( width <= wMax ) {
                    // New fitting shape found, test rectangles
                    for (let top = 0; top <= hMax - height; ++top)
                        for (let left = 0; left <= wMax - width; ++left) {
                            let bottom = top + height,
                                right = left + width,
                                a = tab[top][left];
                            if ( a === tab[bottom][left] &&
                                 a === tab[bottom][right] &&
                                 a === tab[top][right])
                                // Valid rectangle: stop search
                                return [top, left, bottom, right];
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

It performs very well on small arrays, but not on bigger ones. I think it would need an heuristic to quickly find shapes and still stop when a solution is found.

### Approach 2: Mixed efficient search

This solution looks for rectangles, and speeds up when it finds some big ones.

```
function getGreatestRectangleMixed () {
    let greatestArea = 0;
    let greatestRectangle = [];

    // Get horizontal pairs of corners of same color
    // and their vertical positions (y)
    let pairs = {};
    for (let k = 0; k < tab.length; ++k) {
        // Heuristic: alternately search top and bottom
        let y = ( !(k % 2) ? k/2 : tab.length - (k+1)/2);

        let line = tab[y];
        if ( line.length * Math.max(tab.length-y,y+1) < greatestArea )
            break; // Heuristic: height too small

        for (let i = 0; i < line.length - 1; ++i) {
            let color = line[i];
            for (let j = line.length - 1; j > i; --j) {
                if ( (j-i+1) * tab.length < greatestArea )
                    break; // Heuristic: width too small
                if (line[i] === line[j]) {
                    // Pair of corners found
                    let pairKey = i+" "+j;
                    let cornerPair = {
                        corners: [i,j],
                        width: j-i+1,
                        y: y
                    };
                    if (! (color in pairs) )
                        pairs[color] = {};
                    if (! (pairKey in pairs[color]) )
                        // New pair of corners found, keep only first one
                        pairs[color][pairKey] = cornerPair;
                    else {
                        // Rectangle found, check area
                        let isCurrentBottom = pairs[color][pairKey].y < cornerPair.y;
                        let top = (isCurrentBottom ? pairs[color][pairKey] : cornerPair);
                        let bottom = (isCurrentBottom ? cornerPair : pairs[color][pairKey]);
                        let area = top.width * (bottom.y - top.y + 1);
                        if (area > greatestArea) {
                            greatestArea = area;
                            greatestRectangle = [
                                [top.corners[0], top.y],
                                [top.corners[1], top.y],
                                [bottom.corners[0], bottom.y],
                                [bottom.corners[1], bottom.y]
                            ];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return greatestRectangle;
}
```

This solution is a bit slower than the previous one on rectangles of the size of the OP, but more stable with bigger rectangles.

Comment: Approach 2 has a time complexity of _O(n²m)_ for _n_ rows and _m_ columns, correct? Its complexity is equivalent to hashing every vertical pair of corners to the column they appear in (_n²_), and for each column (_m_) building and/or looking up that hash map to find matching pairs, calculating found rectangles, and keeping only the largest ones. I’ve tried hashing so many different things, like rows to corners, corners to rows, row–row matches to columns, rectangle parts to other parts; I just can’t avoid eventually “checking every permutation” of _something_ to get down to _O(nm)_ time…

Comment: I mean… other than pre-solving every single array, and looking up the hash in constant time.

Comment: @SebastianSimon: from what I remember, my 2nd solution implements a sort of memoization saying "I found a rectangle of this area, so I stop looking for smaller ones". Worst case it's like you say. But in average it should perform better. I'm sure we can do even better, if that topic is active I may spend some more time another day.

Answer (score 1):

You could get first all same letter positions in dependent arrays and iterate the array for finding the most right and bottom position. Then check if the two other point have the wanted value.

If so push the found rectangel to a temporary result set. Later sort that array or pick directly the maximum area.

```js
var array = [["B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A"], ["B", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"], ["B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B"], ["B", "B", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A"], ["A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "C", "C", "B", "A", "C"], ["A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "C"], ["C", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A"]],
    points = {},
    rectangles = [],
    count=0;

array.forEach((a, i) => a.forEach((b, j) => (points[b] = points[b] || []).push({ j, i })));

Object
    .keys(points)
    .forEach(k => {
        points[k].slice(0,-1).forEach((p, m) => {
            var n = points[k].length,
                q;

            while (n--) {
                q = points[k][n];
                if (p.i < q.i && p.j < q.j && k === array[p.i][q.j] && k === array[q.i][p.j]) {
                    rectangles.push({ key: k, top: p.i, left: p.j, bottom: q.i, right: q.j, size: (q.i - p.i + 1) * (q.j - p.j + 1) });
                }
            }
        });
    });

rectangles.sort((a, b) => b.size - a.size);

console.log(rectangles);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```